# wercker with debian and alpine box and diff

Tags: wercker

I have one werker.yml with a debian box and one with an alpine box. Both with curl installed. A diff command with debian works fine, with alpine I get

```
    diff: unrecognized option: old-line-format=
    BusyBox v1.26.2 (2017-06-11 06:38:32 GMT) multi-call binary.
```

The diff should be the same. Any idea?

Comment: what does the diff command look like?

Comment: you also should probably post the wercker.yml files.  And also how you create your alpine box with curl installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out, that alpine has only a very basic diff within busybox installed. So option old-line-format is not known. I installed diffutils and everything was fine.